# Mutex on specific key/id

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mutex

I'm asking here because I couldn't express myself well enough for Google to understand.

Does there exist a node-module for typescript that allows you to acquire mutex on a specific key/id?

In my project I'm working with a database with version control that forces me to use mutex whenever I update it. If two threads updates the same entry at the same time version errors can occur. The mutex solves this, but creates a massive bottleneck. Only updates to the same entry requires mutex, but my current implementation use the same mutex on all updates to the database. A solution would be some kind of mutex that can be locked for a certain key/id, where locks on different keys can execute concurrently but multiple locks on the same key are forced to execute one after the other. Thus my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found "async-lock" that did what I wanted, installable through npm. No semaphores though.